# Factorising large numbers

Tags: arithmetic

Can I get some hint for this question, please?

I'm told to find the value of $p$ in the following equation

$$\dfrac{1}{(2p-1)^4} = \dfrac{1-2p}{32}$$

Here's my thought process ...

1. I can't possibly expand $(2p-1)^4$ as it will make things harder.
2. So I thought of changing the signs to  $(1-2p)^4$
3. But ... $\dfrac{1}{(1-2p)^4}$  is not equal to $\dfrac{1}{(2p-1)^4}$ right?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: With $1-2p/32$ do you mean $1-p/16$ or $(1-2p)/32$ ?

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{(1-2p)^4}$ _is_ equal to $\dfrac{1}{(2p-1)^4}$, because $(-x)^4=x^4$ for all $x$. But that doesn't help, unless you have written the right-hand side incorrectly. Perhaps it should be $(1-2p)/32$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach, and probably the intended solution:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(2p-1)^4}&=\frac{1-2p}{32}\\[2ex]
(1-2p)(2p-1)^4&=32\\
(-1)(2p-1)(2p-1)^4&=32\\
(2p-1)^5&=-32\\
2p-1&=-2\\
2p&=-1\\
p&=-0.5
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Why do you fear expansion ? The equation $\frac{1}{(2p-1)^4}=\frac{1-2p}{32}$ is equivalent to
$$
(16p^4 - 48p^3 + 64p^2 - 52p + 31)(2p + 1)=0,
$$
which has real solution $p=-\frac{1}{2}$, because the degree $4$ polynomial has no real roots.

Comment: I think the equation is supposed to be $\frac{1}{(2p-1)^4}=\frac{1-2p}{32}$

Comment: @Logophobic Perhaps you are right - I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{1}{(2p-1)^4} = \dfrac{1-2p}{32}=\frac{1}{2^4(p-\frac 12)^4}=\frac{1-2p}{2^5}$$ Thus $$\frac{1}{(p-\frac 12)^4 }=\frac 12 -p\Rightarrow (p-\frac 12)^5=-1$$
Therefore $$p=-\frac12$$